# incorrect upstream snapshot job

Tags: maven, jenkins

In Jenkins, in maven 2 job, when I check 'Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built' for a job, two upstream jobs are added. These are correct projects, but with incorrect versions (for example: 5.0-SNAPSHOT instead of 4.0.3-SNAPSHOT). In the list of fingerprints for a build it is clearly visible, that 5.0-SNAPSHOT version is used.

For now, as a workaround, I have defined job relations manually.

What can cause such problem and how to fix it? What is the exact logic of upstream job detection?

EDIT:
pom looks like this:

```
...
<packaging>pom<packaging>

<modules>
  <module>mod1</module>
  ...
  <module>mod20</module>
</modules>
<properties>
  <project.B.version>5.0-SNAPSHOT</project.B.version>
  ...
</properties>
...
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>project.B.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>Bartifact</artifactId>
      <version>${project.B.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
...
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and then there is module mod1 with:

```
<parent>...</parent>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>project.B.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>Bartifact</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also, it might be worth mentioning, that I have created jobs for all these projects twice, for 2 different versions.
So there are jobs:

- main-5.0-SNAPSHOT
- B-5.0-SNAPSHOT
- main-4.0.3-SNAPSHOT
- B-4.0.3-SNAPSHOT

And for some reason main-5.0-SNAPSHOT has B-4.0.3-SNAPSHOT as upstream project, and main-4.0.3-SNAPSHOT has B-5.0-SNAPSHOT as upstream project. Which is quite weird.

Comment: I've added poms structure to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out the answer - it is a result of a recent bug. More details:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15237
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15367

related to:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12735
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15295